# Gitlab API adding members to a project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm experiencing errors when trying to add users to a Gitlab project using the Gitlab API. I'm using Gitlab version 8.11.0 on CentOS 6.8 and I'm not sure if it is a bug or something I am doing wrong.
The following works fine and gives me a list of project members:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: top_secret" "https://example.com/api/v3/projects/1/members"
```

but when trying to add a members with the following, I get an error message:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: top_secret" "https://example.com/api/v3/projects/1/members/myusername?access_level=30"

{"error":"405 Not Allowed"}
```

Using the web interface I am able to add the user to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Gitlab API documentation was incorrect.

As it's a create action, you should send both the user ID and access levels as named parameters (like you would for creating any other resource).

So something like:

```
https://example.com/api/v3/projects/1/members/?user_id=299&access_level=40
```